VB.NET - Can I use LINQ over a List(of String) to find strings that end with items from another List(of String)?
I have a List(of String) with some names in them.  I have another List(of String) that has suffixes in them, and I was hoping I could use LINQ to pull a list of the names that end with any of the suffixes in that list.
I can do it programmatically using a pair of nested FOR..EACH loops but was wanted to find a cleaner way using LINQ.
I've tried a few different approaches with .Any and .Contains without success.

"I've tried a few different approaches with .Any and .Contains without success." - you should post your attempts.

You should also provide us with sample data in VB.NET format so that we can easily spin up a solution. Your job is to make answering the question as easy as possible. Real code also adds to real clarity.

The answer here is trivial. If you can provide the sample data then I can easily post an answer. I'll follow the question and when it's updated I'll post my answer.

I had a SQL table with some strings and I wanted to match those up with filenames in a directory (matching up the last x characters of the filename against the list of strings from SQL).  I didn't want to iterate through all of the files in either a while or for each loop.
The answer provided by Tim Schmelter worked perfectly for my needs.

You can use Where and String.EndsWith in Any:
Dim matchingNames = names.
    Where(Function(name) suffixes.Any(Function(suffix) name.EndsWith(suffix)))

If you want to compare in a case insensitive manner, use the overload of EndsWith.
